# Oracle circled export

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, exp

I'm trying to export my scheme from Oracle DB server usint exp.exe utility:

```
exp.EXE USERID=myscheme/myscheme@myserve FULL=Y FEEDBACK=1000 FILE=d:\ORACLE\full.dat LOG=d:\ORACLE\full.LOG
```

And in log file I get the next:

```
XP-00091: Exporting unreliable statistics
. . table expot                   DEF$_AQCALL
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 6550
ORA-06550: row 1, column 18:
PLS-00201: identificator 'SYS.DBMS_DEFER_IMPORT_INTERNAL' должен быть объявлен
ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1204
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 323
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION", line 97
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION", line 126
ORA-06512: on  line 1
. . table expot                  DEF$_AQERROR
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 6510
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unchecked exception, 
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION", line 50
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION", line 126
ORA-06512: on  line 1
```

And a few the same cases. After that exeport is circled: I can find the name of any table a few times in log file and it doesn't stop.

Besides I found to solve export errors I need to know the password for SYS scheme but I have no this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `FULL=Y` means you're doing a full export of all schemas in the database, for which the user you're connected as need the `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` role. If you only want to export your schema you don't need `FULL`. From the documentation [on export modes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#SUTIL2660):

> The Export utility supports four modes of operation:
>
> - Full: Exports a full database. Only users with the EXP_FULL_DATABASE role can use this mode. Use the FULL parameter to specify this mode.
> - Tablespace: Enables a privileged user to move a set of tablespaces from one Oracle database to another. Use the TRANSPORT_TABLESPACE
>     parameter to specify this mode.
> - User: Enables you to export all objects that belong to you (such as tables, grants, indexes, and procedures). A privileged user importing
>     in user mode can import all objects in the schemas of a specified set
>     of users. Use the OWNER parameter to specify this mode in Export.
> - Table: Enables you to export specific tables and partitions. A privileged user can qualify the tables by specifying the schema that
>     contains them. For any table for which a schema name is not specified,
>     Export defaults to the exporter's schema name. Use the TABLES
>     parameter to specify this mode.

So you want a user-mode export, so change `FULL=Y` to `OWNER=myscheme` in your command.

Since you're on 10g you should consider using [data pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm) rather than the legacy export tool.